# In TotalCommander, how do I step into the directory of a found file?

Tags: total-commander

When searching for files in TotalCommander and then clicking *Apply* to view all results in the program window, how do I change into the folder of one of the displayed files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Total Commander 9.0, you may press Ctrl+B to jump from a file in the Search Result pane to the directory of the file under the cursor.

(Source: [Total Commander 9.0 Release Notes](http://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=44181))